# How to know if MySQL is using SSL to connect to a remote database?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

Here is my code to connect to my remote DB:

```
$con = mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($con, "/etc/letsencrypt/keys/...certbot.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../cert.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../fullchain.pem", NULL, NULL);
$connection = mysqli_real_connect($con, self::$host, self::$user, self::$password);
self::$lastConnection = $connection;
$db = "db_prod";
```

Unfortunately, I cannot tell if it's actually working because if I intentionally mispell any of the characters for my certificates in mysqli_ssl_set, the connection is still successful. So how can I know for sure that this is working as intended?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have used mysqli_ssl_set to try establishing SSL connection to MySQL. The system will proceed to use it for subsequent connection request.

Hence, You may check the $connection which is the return value of mysqli_real_connect

So please amend to:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($con, "/etc/letsencrypt/keys/...certbot.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../cert.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../fullchain.pem", NULL, NULL);


$connection = mysqli_real_connect($con, self::$host, self::$user, self::$password);

/////////////////
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
/////////////////

self::$lastConnection = $connection;
$db = "db_prod";

?>
```